# Thread 1 Error on audioPlayer.isPlaying Statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to perform an if statement when the viewDidLoad with my audioPlayer. Basically saying that if the audioPlayer is playing, then pause it. Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.pause()
        }
}
```

But, on line 5 *(starting the if statement)*, I get the error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, adress=0x48)

How can I fix this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hard to say without more code or more error details, but my first guess is that `audioPlayer` is an implicitly unwrapped optional and it's nil at that point.

Comment: Basically, audioPlayer is made by 'var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()'   Also for the error, that's all I get lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the default `NSObject` initializer here - `AVAudioPlayer` doesn't override it, so it doesn't set the `isPlaying` property (or any of its other properties).  You have to use one of the initializers that it actually implements:

```
/* For all of these init calls, if a return value of nil is given you can check outError to see what the problem was.
 If not nil, then the object is usable for playing
*/

/* all data must be in the form of an audio file understood by CoreAudio */
public init(contentsOf url: URL) throws

public init(data: Data) throws


/* The file type hint is a constant defined in AVMediaFormat.h whose value is a UTI for a file format. e.g. AVFileTypeAIFF. */
/* Sometimes the type of a file cannot be determined from the data, or it is actually corrupt. The file type hint tells the parser what kind of data to look for so that files which are not self identifying or possibly even corrupt can be successfully parsed. */
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public init(contentsOf url: URL, fileTypeHint utiString: String?) throws

@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public init(data: Data, fileTypeHint utiString: String?) throws
```